# Inbound email alias for application users - AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

Scenario -

1. Users signup on my website and create an account
2. A particular use case requires the website to provide email aliases for each user so that they can forward some data over email for further processing by the application
3. The email alias is used to identify which user data to use for further processing. There is no need for a real “mailbox” to store emails long term

I am using AWS SES for outbound emails at the moment but have not come across documentation on how to programmatically create inbound email aliases. Has anyone solved a similar situation - am sure the solution is simple but it is eluding me. Thanks in advance for your help